# How to execute the failure scenario for the catch block of the method

Tags: android, mockito, powermockito

Below is the code for which I want to write the test case ,

```
   public static void createFileAndSave(String tag, String logText, File logFile) {
            try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true))) {
                bufferedWriter.write(getCurrentDate() + "   " + tag + "   " + logText + "\r\n");
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            } catch (NullPointerException | IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't write the file  = " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

And I have written the test cases for it , as goes in the catch block of the actuall method but in catch block when I debug ex.getMessage come as null.

```
 @Test
public void testWriteToFileException() {
    File file  = mock(File.class);
    try {
        when(file.getAbsolutePath()).thenReturn("/data/user/0/logs/logs.txt");
        when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
        Logger.createFileAndSave("text", "text" ,file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(e instanceof NullPointerException);
    }
}
```

Where "/data/user/0/logs/logs.txt" is the wrong path to throw an exception.

output : ex.getMessage() result come as null.

Can anyone suggest any better way to mock this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean...you _are_ getting an exception.  If you weren't, there wouldn't be anything to call `getMessage()` _on_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I  add a throw Nullpointer exception in the catch block of the method createFileAndSave() then the catch block of the test cases will be executed.

```
public static void createFileAndSave(String tag, String logText, File logFile) {
            try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true))) {
                bufferedWriter.write(getCurrentDate() + "   " + tag + "   " + logText + "\r\n");
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            } catch (NullPointerException | IOException ex) {
                throws(NullPointerException);
            }
        }
```